# How are these quoted strings replaced with the values in perl .pm file?

Tags: perl

Below is the Perl code in .pm file which is supposed to replace the specified strings (that are in "quotes") with some values. But its not happening. Can anyone explain what is happening in this code?

```
package SomePackage;

require Exporter;

@ISA    = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT = qw(send_request, create_mmd_and_transfer, update_mmd_file);

sub send_request {
    my ( $service, $action, $torole ) = @_;

    my ( $seller_request_mmd );

    my $replace_contents = ();
    $replace_contents{"REPLACE_Service"}        = $service;
    $replace_contents{"REPLACE_RequestAction"}  = $action;
    $replace_contents{"REPLACE_TradingPartner"} = $torole;
    $replace_contents{"REPLACE_Requestxml"}     = "Request.xml";

    create_mmd_and_transfer( \%replace_contents, $seller_request_mmd, "/MMD.xml" );
}

sub create_mmd_and_transfer {

    my $local_replace_contents = shift;
    my $input_mmd              = shift;
    my $local_output_mmd       = shift;
    my $output_mmd             = shift;

    update_mmd_file( "$input_mmd", "temp_mmd_file.xml", $local_replace_contents );
}

sub update_mmd_file {

    my $input_file  = shift;
    my $output_file = shift;
    my $contents    = shift;

    open( MMD_FILE, "<$input_file" )
            or main::error_exit(" Cannot open MMD file template $input_file \n $input_file not found int the Templates folder \n Please place the same and then run the script ");

    open( TEMP_MMD_FILE, ">$output_file" );

    while ( <MMD_FILE> ) {

        s/^M//g;    # Getrid of the ^Ms

        foreach my $content ( keys( %$contents ) ) {

            my $exact_value = ${%$contents}{$content};

            if ( $main::test_scenario =~ /^Invalid Request Action \a\n\d Service/
                and ( $content =~ /REPLACE_Service|REPLACE_RequestAction/i ) ) {
            }
            else {

                if ( $exact_value ne "" ) {
                    s/$content/$exact_value/g;
                }
            }
        }

        print TEMP_MMD_FILE;
    }

    close MMD_FILE;
    close TEMP_MMD_FILE;
}
```

Comment: As it was said to you yesterday, add `use strict; use warnings;` at the beginning of your script. Then you'll notice that you should be going `my %replace_contents` instead of `my $replace_contents`. Moreover, this code is a bit weird: `create_mmd_and_transfer` isn't called with enough parameters, and regardless, it basically does nothing but discarding arguments and calling another function. Also, please indent your code properly, it will be much easier for us to read.

Comment: I am very new to perl coding. This code is given to me and i need to make it work. I am unable to understand, why its not replacing the contents. I will try as u suggested @Dada

Comment: I really recommend you start by learning Perl (at least the basics, with a book or a tutorial) then. Anyway, please show us some data (your input file - or at least a minimalistic working example; and how `send_request` is called exactly) so we can see for ourselves what is happening.

Comment: 1/ Add `use warnings` and `use strict` (and then fix the errors they reveal). 2/ Fix the indentation in the code. 3/ Check the return values from any file opens and take appropriate action (`open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!`).

Comment: I have the feeling that there is also some CGI in the mix.

Answer (score 0):

The following will not make your script work, just create the better base for some future questions.

Before you even thinking about posting a `perl` question here:

1.) add to the top of your script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Posting a code here without these two lines, nobody will bother even trying to read the code.

2.) use `perl -c SomePackage.pm` for the check. If it will tell you: `SomePackage.pm syntax OK` - you can start thinking about posting a question here. ;)

Some basic problems with your script:

```
package SomePackage;
use strict;   # see the above
use warnings;

require Exporter;

# these variables are defined outside of this package, so, tell perl this fact. use the `our`
our @ISA    = qw(Exporter);
#the use warnings will warn you about the following line
# @EXPORT = qw(send_request, create_mmd_and_transfer, update_mmd_file);
#the correct one is without commas
our @EXPORT = qw(send_request create_mmd_and_transfer update_mmd_file); #not saying anything about the @EXPORT rudeness. :)

#my $replace_contents = ();
#the $replace_contents is a scalar. Bellow you using a hash. So,
my %replace_contents;
#or use the scalar but the lines bellow should use the hashref notation, e.g.
# $replace_contents->{"REPLACE_Service"} = $service;
# you decide. :)

# the seller_request_mmd contains undef here.
create_mmd_and_transfer( \%replace_contents, $seller_request_mmd, "/MMD.xml");
# also bellow, in the subroutine definition it wants 4 arguments.
# indicates a problem...

# using 2-arg open is not the best practice.
# Also, you should to use lexical filehandles
# open (MMD_FILE, "<$input_file") 
# better
open (my $mmd_file, '<', $input_file)
# of course, you need change every MMD_FILE to $mmd_file
# check the result of the open and die if not successful
# or you can use the 
use autodie;

# instead of $exact_value = ${%$contents}{$content};
# you probably want
my $exact_value = $contents->{$content};
```

Indent your code!

All the above are just about the syntactic problems and not solving anything about the "logic" of your code.

*Ps: And me is still an beginner, so, others sure will find much more problems with the above code.*

Comment: Is that an attempt to answer the question at the bottom? Maybe they didn't think it was?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Here's what I've done to test this.

Firstly, you didn't give us an input file or the code that you use to call the module. So I invented them. I made the simplest possible input file:

```
REPLACE_Service
REPLACE_RequestAction
REPLACE_TradingPartner
REPLACE_Requestxml
```

And this driver program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use SomePackage;

send_request('foo', 'bar', 'baz');

sub error_exit {
  die @_;
}
```

The first time, I ran it, I got this error:

> Undefined subroutine &main::send_request called at test line 8.

That was because your `@EXPORT` line was wrong. You had:

```
@EXPORT = qw(send_request, create_mmd_and_transfer, update_mmd_file);
```

But the point of `qw(...)` is that you don't need the commas. So I corrected it to:

```
@EXPORT = qw(send_request create_mmd_and_transfer update_mmd_file);
```

Then I re-ran the program and got this error:

> Cannot open MMD file template
>    not found int the Templates folder 
>   Please place the same and then run the script  at test line 11.

That looked like there was something missing. I changed the error message, adding indicators of where the variable interpolation was supposed to happen:

```
open( MMD_FILE, "<$input_file" )
        or main::error_exit(" Cannot open MMD file template <$input_file> \n <$input_file> not found int the Templates folder \n Please place the same and then run the script ");
```

Then the error message looked like this:

> Cannot open MMD file template <> 
>    <> not found int the Templates folder 
>   Please place the same and then run the script  at test line 11.

So it seems clear that the `$input_file` variable isn't set in the `update_mmd_file()` subroutine. Tracing that variable back, we see that this value is originally the `$seller_request_mmd` variable in `send_request()`. But in `send_request()` you declare `$seller_request_mmd` but you never give it a value. So let's do that:

```
my ( $seller_request_mmd ) = 'test_input.txt';
```

Now, when I run your program, it runs to completion without any errors. And I find a new `temp_mmd_file.xml` is generated. But it is exactly the same as the input file. So more investigation is needed.

Digging into the `update_mmd_file()` subroutine, we find this interesting line:

```
my $exact_value = ${%$contents}{$content};
```

I think you're trying to extract a value from `$contents`, which is a hash reference. But your syntax is wrong. You were probably aiming at:

```
my $exact_value = ${$contents}{$content};
```

But most Perl programmers prefer the arrow notation for working with reference look-ups.

```
my $exact_value = $contents->{$content};
```

Making that change and re-running the program, I get an output file that contains:

```
foo
bar
baz
Request.xml
```

Which is exactly what I expected. So the program now works.

But there is still a lot of work to do. As you have been told repeatedly, you should always add:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

to your code. That will find a lot of potential problems in your code - which you should fix.

To be honest, this feels to me like you were trying to run before you could walk. I'd recommend spending some time to work through [a good Perl introductory book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920049517.do) before taking on my more Perl work.

And there was a lot of useful information missing from your question. It wouldn't have taken as long to get to the solution if you had shown us your driver program and your input data.

Comment: Does anyone else know that feeling when you spend an hour debugging someone else's code and you get no response - not even an acknowledgement :-(

Comment: I apologize. Issue was taken & resolved by my team member(perl programmer) & I was completely occupied with some other work. I didn't get time to look into it again or understand the resolution.